# PHP Basics - How to remove Notice

Tags: php, joomla, error-handling, joomla2.5, syntax-error

I accept that am not much aware of php guidelines, 
Need help - if possible on some basic php notices. Though they can be safely ignored by turning off error reporting. But, as what say learning comes through on job experience

Have turned on error reporting to maximum
There are 2 sample notice - which is occurrent on many pages with different variable are

A) Notice: Undefined variable: list in /home/truecar7/public_html/components/com_toys/products/search.php on line 45

B) Undefined property: stdClass::$prod_small_pic in /home/truecar7/public_html/components/com_toys/models/category.php on line 180

Function for A is :-

```
function brand_drop_down(){
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication();
$option = JRequest::getCmd('option');
global $Itemid; 
$database = &JFactory::getDBO();
$sql = "SELECT * from #__toys_products where cat_status='1'  order by cat_sorder Asc";
$database->setQuery($sql);
$rows = $database->loadObjectList();
$list.="";
foreach($rows as $row){
$list.="<option value='".$row->cat_id."' style='padding-left:10px;'>".$row->cat_name."</option>";
}
return $list;
```

Function for B is

```
$database->setQuery($sql);
$rows = $database->loadObjectList();
$list="";
if($rows){
$flg=0;
foreach($rows as $row){
if($row->prod_small_pic!=""){
$img = "uploads/products/".$row->cat_image;
}else{
$img="templates/pioneer_home/images/dvd1.jpg";
}
```

I can see that the variables - list and prod_small_pic are not defined. I think that they are empty string.

I mean how to define them or rather the best way to remove error notices like this. Seeing, many error notices on multiple pages but with different variable

Comment: What is `$list .= ""` supposed to accomplish? You're adding nothing to a variable that never existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function for A:

```
function brand_drop_down(){
    $mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication();
    $option = JRequest::getCmd('option');
    global $Itemid; 
    $database = &JFactory::getDBO();
    $sql = "SELECT * from #__toys_products where cat_status='1'  order by cat_sorder Asc";
    $database->setQuery($sql);
    $rows = $database->loadObjectList();
    // ***** changed next line
    $list="";
    foreach($rows as $row){
        $list.="<option value='".$row->cat_id."' style='padding-left:10px;'>".$row->cat_name."</option>";
    }
    return $list;
}
```

Function B

```
$database->setQuery($sql);
$rows = $database->loadObjectList();
$list="";
if($rows){
    $flg=0;
    foreach($rows as $row){
        // ***** changed next line
        if(isset($row->prod_small_pic) && $row->prod_small_pic !==""){
            $img = "uploads/products/".$row->cat_image;
        }else{
            $img="templates/pioneer_home/images/dvd1.jpg";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Line 45 looks like it's initializing variable, but it not, it should be `$list="";`

Line 80 looks for property in $row, but it doesn't contain it. Perhaps you don't select it in query? Try `print_r($row)` to see what is in there.

Also, `global $Itemid;` - isn't it possible to make it a function argument? `function brand_drop_down($Itemid){`